How to wait for a confirmation dialog in Flet?
I press a button, a confirmation popup should appear and based on the option you picked(ex: yes or no) to decide what to do next.
Using flet==0.22.*

the easiest way to do it,
here is the sample code, I'm using same 0.22 felt version
import flet as ft

def main(page):
    def show_confirmation_dialog(message):
        confirmation_dialog = ft.AlertDialog(
            title="Confirmation",
            content=message,
            buttons=[
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="Yes", on_click=lambda _: handle_confirmation(True)),
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="No", on_click=lambda _: handle_confirmation(False))
            ]
        )
        page.add(confirmation_dialog)
        page.update()

    def handle_confirmation(confirmed):
        page.remove(page.controls[-1])  # Remove the confirmation dialog
        page.update()

        if confirmed:
            # Perform actions based on the "Yes" choice
            print("User confirmed the action.")
        else:
            # Perform actions based on the "No" choice
            print("User canceled the action.")

    # Create a button that triggers the confirmation dialog
    button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Show Confirmation", on_click=lambda _: show_confirmation_dialog("Are you sure you want to proceed?"))
    page.add(button)

    page.update()
ft.app(target=main)


Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=TypeError("AlertDialog.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buttons'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
.....in 
button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Show Confirmation", on_click=lambda _: show_confirmation_dialog("Are you sure you want to proceed?"))
File "/home/alex/projects/flet-orm/confirm2.py", line 5, in show_confirmation_dialog
confirmation_dialog = ft.AlertDialog(
TypeError: AlertDialog.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buttons'

I found 3 solution(s) and for simplicity I'll base my example on @EvilReboot example
I will leave all bellow in case someone might prefer one over another.
Solution 1 - Using lambda
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    def show_confirmation_dialog(message):
        confirmation_dialog = ft.AlertDialog(
            modal=True,
            title=ft.Text("Confirmation"),
            content=ft.Text(message),
            actions=[
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="Yes", on_click=lambda _: handle_confirmation(True)),
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="No", on_click=lambda _: handle_confirmation(False))
            ],
        )
        page.show_dialog(confirmation_dialog)

    def handle_confirmation(confirmed):
        if confirmed:
            # Perform actions based on the "Yes" choice
            print("User confirmed the action.")
        else:
            # Perform actions based on the "No" choice
            print("User canceled the action.")
        page.close_dialog()

    # Create a button that triggers the confirmation dialog
    button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Show Confirmation",
                               on_click=lambda _: show_confirmation_dialog("Are you sure you want to proceed?"))
    page.add(button)
    page.update()


ft.app(target=main)

Solution 2 - Using event's originating control
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    def show_confirmation_dialog(message):
        confirmation_dialog = ft.AlertDialog(
            modal=True,
            title=ft.Text("Confirmation"),
            content=ft.Text(message),
            actions=[
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="Yes", on_click=handle_confirmation),
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="No", on_click=handle_confirmation)
            ],
        )
        page.show_dialog(confirmation_dialog)

    def handle_confirmation(e):
        confirmed = True if e.control.text == 'Yes' else False
        if confirmed:
            # Perform actions based on the "Yes" choice
            print("User confirmed the action.")
        else:
            # Perform actions based on the "No" choice
            print("User canceled the action.")
        page.close_dialog()

    # Create a button that triggers the confirmation dialog
    button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Show Confirmation",
                               on_click=lambda _: show_confirmation_dialog("Are you sure you want to proceed?"))
    page.add(button)
    page.update()


ft.app(target=main)

Solution 3 - Using arbitrary data field (of Control)
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    def show_confirmation_dialog(message):
        confirmation_dialog = ft.AlertDialog(
            modal=True,
            title=ft.Text("Confirmation"),
            content=ft.Text(message),
            actions=[
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="Yes", data=True, on_click=handle_confirmation),
                ft.ElevatedButton(text="No", data=False, on_click=handle_confirmation)
            ],
        )
        page.show_dialog(confirmation_dialog)

    def handle_confirmation(e):
        confirmed = e.control.data
        if confirmed:
            # Perform actions based on the "Yes" choice
            print("User confirmed the action.")
        else:
            # Perform actions based on the "No" choice
            print("User canceled the action.")
        page.close_dialog()

    # Create a button that triggers the confirmation dialog
    button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Show Confirmation",
                               on_click=lambda _: show_confirmation_dialog("Are you sure you want to proceed?"))
    page.add(button)
    page.update()


ft.app(target=main)

